# JPA hibernate single table multiple inheritance/discriminator

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I need to store emails that are received and sent in the same table.
Any `outEmail` can be sent again, `inEmail` can't. I'd like these objects to be dressed this way so its harder to make that mistake in the service layer.

That, and certain inEmails have certain behaviours associated with them. This the hierarchy id like:

Email -> outEmail -> customerOut

Email -> inEmail -> customerIn, supplierIn

So outEmail objects are the only kind that can get sent out again.
I thought I'd try it like this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="direction")
@Table(name="email")
public abstract class Email{

}
```

inEmail:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="role")
@DiscriminatorValue("IN")
public abstract class InEmail extends Email {

}
```

customerIn:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CUSTOMER")
public class customerIn extends InEmail {

}
```

At customerIn, it uses the discriminator value at inEmail. Is what I am trying to do possible, or do I need an alternative?